# Apache server sometimes return 500 but fixed after refresh

Tags: iptables, firewall, wordpress

I have a wordpress website hosted by a Apache HTTP Server. This website previously works normally but recently it sometimes return 500 and says:

```
This page isn’t working

xxx.xxx.xxx is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

However after refresh, it works again. This might happened roughly every 50 requests.

The change I have added recently is an `iptables` rule to prevent the Brute force attack:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 50/min --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
```

And also a long list of DROPed ip like this:

```
-A INPUT -s xx.xx.xx.xx/32 -j DROP
```

So anyone has similar experience like this? Is this an hardware issue or software? Thank you very much!

Comment: That is not an Apache error page. Look for other things in the path between you and the server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton My server hosted in school Internet and I have a hardware Firewall. However after I remove the Firewall same issue still happens.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am wondering whether is my machine too old to handle the website or the university Internet issue. So if it's due to machine cannot handle the request it will show the Apache error page, right? Thanks.

Comment: What Apache error page?

Comment: Something like this: [error page](http://www.elated.com/res/Image/articles/management/apache/making-a-custom-error-page/apache_404_default.gif). Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: I know what an Apache error page is. But your question doesn't mention one at all. So I don't understand why you brought it up.

Comment: I just want to know whether is my machine too old issue or as you said the other things in the path between me and the server. Anyway I will check with the school Internet first. Thanks.

Comment: We need to see the access and error log entries to help diagnose this problem. Is it just serving static content (html, images, etc), or does it use PHP or something else to generate pages? If it does you need to check those logs as well. This problem is very unlikely to be related to server age.